# How to get xml value from table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
<SSRSReport>
  <OutputType>email</OutputType>
  <email>
    <emailTo>xyz.com</emailTo>
    <emailReplyTo>dd@gmail.com</emailReplyTo>
    <emailSubject>status report</emailSubject>
    <emailBody>
</email>
</SSRSReport>
```

Need your help on selecting node value of  in sql from table existing in one column of xml type. What I already tried is :

```
select 
   T.id, 
   T.xml_data.value('(SSRSReport/email/@emailTo)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as PropertyName 
from 
   abc as T 
where 
   T.xml_data.exist('/email/emailTo') = 'xyz.com'
```

but it returns property name column as null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close - but since `<emailTo>` is an **element** (not an attribute), you need to use:

```
select 
T.id, 
T.xml_data.value('(SSRSReport/email/emailTo)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as PropertyName
```

Use `/emailTo` (not `/@emailTo`) as the last part of your XPath expression.

Also, the `.exist()` function can only check for the presence of a XML element (or attribute), so you could check to see if a `<emailTo>` element exists (or does not exist), but you cannot compare to a value. So your `WHERE` clause is invalid - you probably wanted:

```
where 
   T.xml_data.value('(SSRSReport/email/emailTo)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'xyz.com'
```